# What is the meaning of 'state visit with France'?

Tags: word-usage

I read the news headline in an [Indian daily](http://indianexpress.com/article/world/melania-trump-us-france-state-visit-donald-macron-brigitte-white-hat-5150782/) that stats:

> US First lady Melania Trump steps into spotlight for ***state visit with France***

I think it should be 'state visit **to France**' instead of 'state visit of France'. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You're right **if** France refers to a location. That is not the case here. Instead, France refers to Emmanuel Macron (and his wife) since he represents the country as its president. The usage of France here is figurative, symbolic, not literal. We can use *with* with a person(s) and say *a visit **with** someone*:

> - a visit with Alice
>     *visiting, meeting Alice*
> - a visit to France
>     *visiting, experiencing the country of France*
> - a visit with France
>     *visiting, meeting the president of France*

Answer (score 1):

Either *state visit to France* or *state visit with France* are suitable. Do note that this being a headline, many English conventions are ignored in the interest of brevity, in a telegraphic dialect jocularly known as *[headlinese](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2014/dec/04/sub-ire-as-hacks-slash-word-length-getting-the-skinny-on-thinnernyms)*.

A *[state visit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_visit)* is not a visit to a state, but a visit of one head of state to another, usually a highly ceremonial and diplomatically fraught affair. Like any kind of [visit](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/visit_2), one can *pay a visit to* a person or place (to go and spend time in another place), or you can *have a visit with* a person:

> **visit (with somebody)** (*North American English, informal*) an occasion when two or more people meet to talk in an informal way [OALD]

As the primary purpose of a state visit is not to tour the country but to have the guest's officials meet with the host's officials, a *visit with France* is appropriate [synecdoche](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/synecdoche.htm) referring to the American delegation meeting with French officials and diplomats.